# Error connection JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have problem. When I try to connect to a remote database on the server. I get this exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have shortened full stack trace.

I seem to close all the connections. Everything works on the local database, what's the problem? Here is an example of connecting

```
    public static Connection getConnection()
        throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://zrn.mysql.ukraine.com.ua:3306/zrn_program?" +
                    "autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
            "USERNAME",
            "PASSWORD");
}
```

Sample queries

```
public static List<Training> showTraining(String date){

    List<Training> trainings = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection con = Connector.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM view_training" +
                 " WHERE training_date = ?")){
        pst.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(date));
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
            trainings.add(new Training(rs.getInt("training_id"),rs.getString("patient"),
                    rs.getString("specialist"),rs.getString("training_date"),
                    rs.getString("training_time"),rs.getBoolean("hasTicket"),
                    rs.getString("category"),rs.getString("status"),rs.getDouble("sum"),
                    rs.getString("color")));
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return trainings;
}
```

Help, please.

UPD1

this full stack trace

```
om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2088)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at database.Connector.getConnection(Connector.java:13)
at database.DBTraining.showConsultation(DBTraining.java:268)
at servlet.views.Main.doGet(Main.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
    ... 37 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 39 more
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: i added the full stack trace

Comment: Mayne a firewall blocking access?

Comment: Make sure that your database server is up in the specified url.

Comment: is your mysql server up and running?

Comment: You can check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848000/java-mysql-connect-to-server/38848473#38848473 This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your remote database is not visible for remote access, so your program cannot connect to your database server ([compare this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637604/jdbc-could-not-create-connection-to-database-server)).

You should check you are able to connect with the mysql command line client, to your remote database.

Comment: I can connect, it works, and then it crashes.